# How to get today's / yesterday's data from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to retrive a TODAY'S data from the database, but I don't know how to do it. I would actually want to get the data from NOT the past 24 hours, I just want today's data (so based on the actual server time).

I would also like to get data which was yesterday. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Sample code:

```
"SELECT id FROM folk WHERE time = ???"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you storing "time", int, timestamp, datetime etc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
"SELECT id FROM folk WHERE DATE(time) = CURDATE()"
```

time must be a field in you table that holds a reference to the row.

**update**

To get yesterdays additions:

```
"SELECT id FROM folk WHERE DATE(time) = CURDATE() - 1"
```

**update 2**

To get all additions this month:

```
"SELECT id FROM folk 
WHERE MONTH(time) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(time) = YEAR(NOW())"
```

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: No man I'm actually looking to get data from the ACTUAL DAY based on server time. Like its 8am here so it should show me data only from the last 8 hours not more.

Comment: I think that is what I am providing. Each record needs a timestamp when it was created. MySQL holds no log of added records.

Comment: Than how can I get yesterdays, or monthly data with this?

Comment: Updated my answer. To get all data from this month is a bit more complex, but on the other hand that was not the question.

Comment: "SELECT id FROM folk WHERE DATE(time) = CURDATE()"
Its actually not showing anything from the database :/

Comment: NVM Its working man! Thank you. I haven't thought that it could work, but it does :) I have just miswritten something.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id FROM folk WHERE DATE(time) = DATE(NOW());

SELECT id FROM folk WHERE DATE(time) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

provided that 'time' has a proper date-time type

Comment: `time`'s a timestamp, as the OP explains in his comment (which might have been posted after your answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this>>

```
SELECT id from folk  WHERE DAY( date ) = EXTRACT(DAY from (NOW() - inTERVAL 
1 DAY ) )
```

Refer this link
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum112/278.htm

Answer (score 1):

As you are using timestamp:

```
"SELECT id FROM folk WHERE time >= ".mktime(0, 0, 0)
```

That will select all data since beginning today.

If you want to get all date not for today, you would do

```
"SELECT id FROM folk WHERE time < ".mktime(0, 0, 0)
```

To select data from yesterday, you would do:

```
"SELECT id FROM folk WHERE time < ".mktime(0, 0, 0)." AND time >= ".mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')-1, date('Y'))
```

If you were to use DATETIME, just for reference, it would be something like:

```
"SELECT id FROM folk WHERE time >= '".date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00."'"
```

Comment: note that string concatenation is frowned upon in SQL queries; yes, I know this is only an example

Comment: "SELECT id FROM folk WHERE time >= ".mktime(0, 0, 0)
Its actually not working. It gives me all the data, not just that day :/

Comment: Hmm, it should be working? I've tested the timestamps and they are accurate, so I can only assume that the comparison is failing or it isn't able to match the two against each other.

@tucuxi I know, but trying to keep it short and sweet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Get current date by using something like following query

```
SELECT * 
 FROM your_table_name 
WHERE DAY('.$colum_name.') = DAY("2018-05-02")';
```