# SQL - Yesterday's date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query:

```
SELECT ....
WHERE CalendarDateTime.StartDate >= NOW()
```

How can I change the `NOW()` part to reference yesterday?

Comment: Try the solution in this question, but with a minus operator.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887509/mysqls-now-1-day

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get today's / yesterday's data from MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551883/how-to-get-todays-yesterdays-data-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT ....
WHERE CalendarDateTime.StartDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

But I guess `StartDate` is a DATE and what you actually want is to include today's events, which your current solution does only at midnight. In that case the more appropriate solution is:

```
SELECT ....
WHERE CalendarDateTime.StartDate >= DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: This seems to be from Silverstripe Event Calendar where StartDate seems to be a Date, so see my revised answer.