# PHP- working with date and time

Tags: php, date, cakephp, datetime, strtotime

I need to retrieve a date of this format `2014-17-02 00:00:00` , where the hours minutes and seconds are just zeros, meaning I want today as the day started after midnight, or yesterday `2014-16-02 23:59:59pm` depending on how you look at it.

The reason I want to retrieve this kind of datetime is so that I can effectively compare my 'created' field inside the database, allowing me to obtain records inserted 'today'..

Any suggestions? I have tried these:

```
$this->today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $this->today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
```

But they seem to do the same thing(give me datetime in accuracy of hh mm ss) which is not what I want.

I want to execute this query

```
"SELECT users.role as user_role, 
            Count(users.role) AS user_count
            FROM users
            WHERE users.created >= '$this->today' // any record created after yest midnight
            GROUP BY users.role"
```

Comment: `'Y-m-d 00:00:00'` – D’oh?

Comment: ...or use 'Y-m-d' with `DATE(users.created)`

Comment: @CBroe I feel stupid not to have tried that. I assumed it is just used to imply the format of the returned results just like h:i:s thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->today = date('Y-m-d') . '00:00:00';
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: I went with what @CBroe said in his comment! both work though so marking as answered! Ofc concatenation! how did I not think of that one, simple yet effective!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to calculate this purely using SQL - one less clock to worry about.

[SQL - Yesterday's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463203/sql-yesterdays-date)

```
SELECT ....
WHERE users.created >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. Though it is not equivalent to `$this->today = date('Y-m-d') . '00:00:00';` or `$this->today = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');`

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT users.role as user_role, 
 Count(users.role) AS user_count
 FROM users
 WHERE DATE(users.created) >= '$this->today'
 GROUP BY users.role
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

i think replace this with

```
 $this->today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days")); // get yesterday date to
```

Comment: Logically, I think this wouldn't work for me as I need to obtain records created after midnight yesterday, and not records created yesterday.

Comment: its give yesterday date and in your query get recorde >= yesterday date, it means you get whole record which is create today, i hope u are understand

Comment: This will also retrieve records created yesterday. I think you meant to use the '>' n operator, rather than '>=' . I can see that would work!

Comment: sorry it my foult i was forget to change this one >= to >