# how can i write as one query to get count in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

I want to get the today count of users and yesterday's users count for that i want to write only one query how can i do that..?

these are my queries I want only one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitors group by visited_date ORDER by visited_date DESC limit 1,1 as todayCount

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitors group by visited_date ORDER by visited_date DESC limit 1,0 as yesterdayCount
```

My expected results or only 2 columns

```
todayCount yesterdayCount
     2          4
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551883/how-to-get-todays-yesterdays-data-from-mysql-database

Comment: Can you try this `SELECT SUM(visited_date ='2017-07-06') AS yesterdayCount ,
   SUM(visited_date  ='2017-07-07') AS todayCount 
FROM visitors`  and let me know please

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: simply you can set limit to 2

Comment: Your query does not get "yesterday" count and "today" count.  It gets the counts from the most recent two days in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the current and previous date, then you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(visited_date = CURDATE()) as today,
       SUM(visited_date = CURDATE() - interval 1 day) as yesterday
FROM visitors
WHERE visited_date >= CURDATE() - interval 1 day;
```

If you don't know the two days, then you can do something similar, getting the latest date in the data:

```
SELECT SUM(v.visited_date = m.max_vd) as today,
       SUM(v.visited_date < m.max_vd) as yesterday
FROM visitors v CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(v2.visited_date) as max_vd FROM visitors v2) as m
WHERE v.visited_date >= m.max_vd - interval 1 day
```

Comment: The second one is working ... but first one is saying error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'CURDATE' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN visited_date = CURDATE() THEN 1 
             END) AS todayCount ,
       COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN visited_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 1 
             END) AS yesterdayCount 
FROM visitors  
WHERE visited_date IN (CURDATE(), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY visited_date
ORDER by visited_date
```

Comment: should not be `GROUP BY` clause come after `WHERE` clause? like `WHERE visited_date IN (CURDATE(), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY visited_date` ?

Comment: @ravisachaniya Ooops, yes, thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

Just try this simple query

```
select visited_date as date, COUNT(*) as count from `visitors` 
group by `visited_date` order by `visited_date` asc
```

It will produce output as

[image]

It will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
$sqlToday = "Select COUNT(*) FROM menjava WHERE DATE(date_submitted)=CURRENT_DATE()";

$sqlYesterday = "Select COUNT(*) FROM menjava WHERE DATE(dc_created) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";